# Just beginning new internship and another company wants to interview

Tags: interviewing, new-job, internship, training, scheduling

I am beginning a busy-season internship at an accounting firm, January-March. My first day is January 3rd, and I am training at my local office January 3rd-9th and then going to Chicago to train Jan 10th-12th. I assume it is going to be a lot of information to soak up and remember, considering I am a very young, new hire.

Being that this internship is only for the spring, I am still actively looking for a summer internship. A company that I had applied for a summer internship emailed me today and told me that I could choose a time slot and come in to interview on the 4th of January (my second day of training at my new internship, assumedly something that is way too important to skip out on, even for a couple hours).

What is my best course of action here? I will not be done training with my new internship until the 12th, but this other company wants to interview the 4th. Should I request a later date? Request a phone or video interview?

Comment: Don't worry to much in both options. Just ask them to change the interview date.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Rescheduling a Coveted Interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible for you to make it, then make it.  If you absolutely cannot miss the training, then ask if you can reschedule for after the 12th.  The hiring manager should understand that you have an obligation.  It seems unlikely that they wouldn't be willing to wait a week but if the answer is no, you'll have to decide for yourself which is more important.

You could certainly ask to do it over Skype, though I find that it's usually a poor substitute for meeting face to face. There are certain elements of a person's character that can only be learned through face-to-face interaction.

Answer (score 0):

> What is my best course of action here?

Tell the summer internship company that you are busy on the 4th.

Arrange a different time/date to interview - perhaps after work.