# Asking to reschedule an interview because of spontaneous plan to go on vacation on that day

Tags: interviewing, pre-screening, lying

I am in an interesting situation. I work Monday-Thursday (company policy, normal companies work Monday-Friday). I have a Skype interview scheduled for next Friday). Today I realized the upcoming Monday after the interview day is a public holiday here.

I just realized today it's a very good opportunity to go on 4 day vacations. Only problem is this single interview (which is just a short call as part of first round). I want to request them to reschedule it without sounding unprofessional.

I feel if I told them I want to go on holidays rather than interviewing, I feel that's sure way to get rejection mail. I am thinking of lying about being sick a day before and ask them for next Friday. They have no way of knowing if I am resting at home, or on holidays. My social networks are also private so no prospective employer can see them.

My question is, is it professional (considering I have no obligations towards them) and can it backfire on me somehow?

Comment: Is doing your Skype interview from vacation an option?

Comment: i think it's more unprofessional to ask complete strangers what professionalism is

Comment: Is that day not a holiday for the company you are interviewing with?

Comment: @NotMe Presumably not, or they wouldn't have booked it. I assume this is in reference to Easter (and OP's writing style leads me to suspect they are in the same jurisdiction as I am), in which case, many companies give either Friday or Monday off, but _rarely_ both.

Comment: We're not really here to help you come up with an appropriate lie. As shown in your question, you already realise that telling them you're picking holidays over them is a bad idea, but otherwise [rescheduling far enough in advance for a good reason isn't a particularly big deal](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35878/rescheduling-a-coveted-interview).

Comment: @msanford:  I've scheduled interviews with candidates and other meetings on holidays by accident before - hence why I asked.  Sometimes the person setting the date doesn't realize.

Comment: @NotMe Naturally, also why I added my rationale. Maybe a call to confirm is warranted.

Comment: @NotMe Apparently yes it is vacation for everyone including the interviewing company. I just learn about it yesterday (I am a foreigner here). Next Friday-Monday are holidays for everyone.

Comment: Downvotes? Because it's not a good question, or it doesn't say what you want to hear?

Answer (score 4):

If you care about the interview, I wouldn't.

Saying, "I decided to miss my appointment because I wanted to hang out on the beach instead" would sound very bad. An interview is a very special and important work-related day. If you're willing to miss that because of a last-minute decision to take a day off, they'd have to wonder how often you would not bother to show up for work if you got the job.

Saying you're sick is no better and maybe worse. Surely they will consider the possibility that this is an excuse. It's not like you're the first person in the history of the world to claim to be sick as a way of getting out of something. If they believe you really are sick, then they have to be thinking, how bad is this person's health? If he gets sick on what is essentially a random day, how often will he be taking sick leave if he gets the job? But more likely, they'll strongly suspect that you are lying and this is just an excuse to reschedule the interview, in which case you not only get minus points for not giving the interview sufficient priority, but more minus points for (probably) lying about the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course, if you have *committed* to something and then back out, it will not only look unprofessional, it will *be* unprofessional. That's common sense.

In my industry (software engineering) even preliminary interviews often involve a small panel of people who must co-ordinate their time all to be available together. This is not trivial. Even if it's a single person, do show respect for their time.

However, depending on the kind of vacation you want to take and the kind of interview you'll be doing (neither are specified) you may be able to do your interview while on vacation.

You'll need to apply some common-sense: have a quiet environment, not sitting on you hotel bed in a Hawaiian shirt. Will you be staying in a hotel with a meeting room or business centre you can reserve, for example?

This may not be doable, but it's something to consider.

If you take that route, you may want to mention it casually at the start of the call. It may even work in your favour: you're so interested that you took steps to arrange it while on vacation. Just don't be smug about it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when interviewing you don't make last minute changes or anything that stops things going absolutely smoothly. At that point many companies are looking for candidates to weed out, any little thing can be used, they don't know you and have no investment in you.